# What is this encoding and can I decode it?

Tags: jsp, decode, encode

I am analyzing an app and i am receiving some responses from the server like this, i believe it was done in JSP

`ESIMflcbE0PAdevT8ILdgUZ1XNuKpWprIZGw4ml23tGN7c5Mv9myyU8+OCceB++cUooQyogMUH/KDhOjiZv9Dlo6/10zFYWyVkeqtQJdJmPMhTU=`

`MMT ESITm7+ydQPVgZnyUiYUa/VdNg==Mq`

Comment: It's base64-encoded binary data. As for what the binary data is, it's impossible to tell without knowing more about the application, as `11 22` doesn't seem like a common file signature.

Comment: The encoding is base64 (in the second string the part "ESIT.....Ng=="). You can decode it, but the result is binary data.